# Python/ASP.NET/Javascript: How to scrape ASP.NET based page

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, web-scraping

I'm working on a python program which would scrape data (public data) from web pages. The problem is when I want to get source code of a web page which is accessable using button and it's based on ASP.NET. I can't just parse a href from the page as usual.

So my question is: Is there a simple way how to get the source code of the ASP.NET page?

To explain it clearly I'm attaching one web page based on ASP.NET:
In this case I want to get soure code of page which is displayed when I click on "Radiátor topení (1)" in the middle of the page.
 You can see the parent page where is the button on which I want to simulate click [here](http://www.autokelly.cz/#|Y33buV4cvEnkJxvjhfNBp5qoBS6S7ylpNyzxFTblgJ+IIwJ1hnG91bOJEUxEv+G7zorRbTmNDCkrGhun15oxZjxf6xzUEnd5Iknnrap0kUuWLxcWjKC36KLgswQH0Oo+2k9M3EI24SYhKZvQdlG2vscuyMjOhticzgxVondhG5A=)!

I was trying to check source code of this (parent) page and look for some url near the "Radiátor topení (1)" text but I've found only this:

`<td class="CatalogCell"><a onclick=" return PathClick(&#39;3761801;176564;356239;922141;922488;922507;922508&#39;)"><H2 class="CatalogH">Radiátor topení (1)</H2></a></td>`
and I'm afraid, this wont help me.

I'm looking for a simpliest way because I'm not expert in ASP.NET nor Javascript.
Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1):

The program is in python, which gives the html source of the link.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link="http://www.example.com"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(link,headers=hdr)

page = urllib2.urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

print soup
```

Comment: for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
   print "Found the URL:", a['href']

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote, there is no href in the source code of the parent page... so I can't just look on the source code and find a path to page (in this case it is "Radiátor topení (1)")